# XSS source & lt & gt is it correct?

Tags: javascript, java, xss, gt

I found the code for XSS.

```
private String cleanXSS(String value) {  

    value = value.replaceAll("<", "& lt;").replaceAll(">", "& gt;");  
    value = value.replaceAll("\\(", "& #40;").replaceAll("\\)", "& #41;");  
    value = value.replaceAll("'", "& #39;");            
    value = value.replaceAll("eval\\((.*)\\)", "");  
    value = value.replaceAll("[\\\"\\\'][\\s]*javascript:(.*)[\\\"\\\']", "\"\"");  
    value = value.replaceAll("script", "");  
    return value;  
}
```

Is it correct `& lt` `& gt` `& #40` `& #41` `& #39` ?

I think `&lt` `&gt` ... is correct without space between `&` and `lt`.

Comment: In general, it's not very secure to sanitize for XSS yourself. I recommend finding a library that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Replacements with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&#39;` are part of HTML encoding and have their use when outputting in an HTML context. It's missing `&quot;` and `&amp;` though. This is Rule #1 on [OWASP XSS Prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

The rest with `script` and `eval` doesn't make much sense. It can corrupt valid user input. The `eval()` replacement will never match because it's already replaced parenthesis. It checks for `script` but not `SCRIPT`. `scscriptript` is converted into `script`. And there are other ways of executing JS that it doesn't look for.

Trying to look for specific strings doesn't really work. It's better to focus on applying the correct encoding at the time of output, and being careful about where you output values, following the OWASP guides.